# Remove from array using _.pull with regex

Tags: arrays, regex

I have two arrays. One is full of links and the other simple strings that represent the domain of a link. It's more like a blacklist of URLs.

```
links = ['http://www.one.com', ... 'http://www.ten.com']
ignore = ['two, four, nine']
```

I am trying to use regex with `pull`, but passing a regular expression, like:

```
for (let i of iignore) {
  clearedUrls.concat(_.pull(links, `https?:\/\/www.${i}.*`))
}
```

But no success, although testing on Regex101, the expression is correct.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The question title talks about the lodash function `filter`, but in the question you talk about using `pull`....

Comment: Forgive, I wrote it by accident. I was reading and thinking about pull and filter, wrote one but meant another.

Comment: No problem. You do know that in lodash, `pull` doesn't accept a regex as the second parameter. Have you tried `_.remove`?

Comment: Yes, I tried now some ways, but it seems not to affect either. Does `remove` accept regular expressions?

Comment: It accepts a predicate, which you can supply as a function that invokes a regex match. Let me know if you need help composing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `remove` instead, this is the following working code:

```
for (let url of urls) {
  u += `${url.trim()}|`
}

u           = u.substring(0, u.length - 1) // Remove last pipe
let regex   = new RegExp('.*.(' + u + ').com.*', 'g') // https?:\/\/www.(two|four|nine).com.*/g
clearedUrls = clearedUrls.concat(_.remove(links, (obj) => {
  return !obj.match(regex)
}))
```